# Forbidden 403 error on Google AdSense requests

Tags: html, javascript, google-adsense, 403-forbidden

I have created a new [website](http://find-word.zxq.net/) and have set some ads. For some unknown reason, FireBug tells me that I get 403 errors on Google Adsense requests. I have checked my AdSense account and it does not block my new website.

When I open the pages from my PC, the ads are displayed, but I when I try from the website itself, they are not. I can't find much relevant information with Googling.

Does anyone have experience with this? Do you know what is happening? Does it go away by itself? I have also left a question on the Google forum, but did not get an answer yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days, Google Webmaster start sending messages with more information about the issue. It tried to fetch robots.txt several times, but failed. In the mean time, I logged a ticket to my provider and they finally solved the issue.

Apparently, the 503 was sent to Google Bots only. Were Google bots too aggressive? Was the provider's server too sensitive? I don't know, but the issue is solved.

Comment: Can you tell me if that issue returned and if for different reasons ? I get similar errors for many months already.